# ajax completes successfully but returns empty xml

Tags: asp.net, jquery

I am sending an AJAX call to an ASP.NET C# function. The AJAX call completes without problems but the XML response comes back empty. Here is the Javascript code:

```
      $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "Default.aspx/a1",
          data: '{}',
          contentType: "application/json",
          dataType: "text/xml",
          async: true,
          success: function (data) {
              alert("success");                  
              var x = data.documentElement.childNodes[0].childNodes;
              var name = '', value = '', str = '';
              for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
                  //Get node name and its string value
                  name = x[i].nodeName;
                  value = x[i].text;
                  str += name + ':' + value + ', ';
              }                 
              alert(str);                   
          },
          error: function (a, b, c) { alert("problem in Main.aspx"); }
      });
```

Here is the webmethod:

```
[WebMethod]
public static XmlDocument a1()
{
    DataTable table1 = new DataTable("patients");
    table1.Columns.Add("name");
    table1.Columns.Add("id");
    table1.Rows.Add("sam", 1);
    table1.Rows.Add("mark", 2);

    DataTable table2 = new DataTable("medications");
    table2.Columns.Add("id");
    table2.Columns.Add("medication");
    table2.Rows.Add(1, "atenolol");
    table2.Rows.Add(2, "amoxicillin");

    // Create a DataSet and put both tables in it.
    DataSet set = new DataSet("office");
    set.Tables.Add(table1);
    set.Tables.Add(table2);

    // Visualize DataSet.
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.LoadXml(set.GetXml());

    return doc;
}
```

I used Internet Explorer, pressed F12 and captured the network messages the response returns 200 OK, see screenshot:

http://postimg.org/image/705copynl/

when add a watch right at the end of the C# function I see that the XML is populated with data:

http://postimg.org/image/my6rgaril/

but In Visual Studio I add a watch in the AJAX call and realise that the variable data is returning empty!

http://postimg.org/image/atkgmnklp/

and this is verified also in the network message capture by Internet Explorer:

http://postimg.org/image/o32z0hyq5/

What is happening?! Why am I not getting the XML response in Javascript? I have spent days on this trying different alternatives for datatype, I just cannot get an answer in XML! Can anyone please advise on what could be the problem here.

Comment: Silly question, but did you notice that you are returning an `XmlDocument` object, not an xml string?

Comment: have you tried with diff browser,try with firefox or chrome once

Comment: @asawyer if you are referring to the line dataType: "text/xml", I also tried dataType: "xml" but the error function(){} fires. I tried "json" and it still comes back with an empty response :(

Comment: @dreamweiver yes Firefox behaves the same way, I used two plugins called Live HTTP Headers and HTTPFox to catch AJAX messages and both tools show an empty response coming back.

Comment: No, I'm referring to this `public static XmlDocument a1()` Shouldn't it be `public static string a1(){ ... return doc.ToString(); }`

Comment: Aha I see what you mean, well with return doc.ToString() all I get is "{"d":"System.Xml.XmlDocument"}" when AJAX returns. If I make it return set.GetXml(); then I get a string containing the XML data but with lots of \n and \r characters.

Comment: Youll need to look at the documentation to find the appropriate method that returns the xml string back to javascript.

Comment: Is it not possible to have the function return a type of XmlDocument and get back the entire XML assembly as is? Why do I have to utilise a string and return that one, is this the norm? Apologies if my questions are silly or tiresome as I am rather new to all this.

Comment: The Ajax request is asking for and expecting to get back an Xml string. It has **no concept of the .Net CLR Runtime and its types**.